# Can I trim this MDF closet door from Wayfair to fit my closet?

Tags: closet

I have found this closet door which I like on Wayfair. The doors height is 78" and they recommend a opening height of 80" but *my closet opening height is 79"*. I am wondering if I can trim about an inch off the bottom of this door to make it fit.  It's a sliding door with top track only and they say it's made of 'solid MDF and covered with eco-friendly finishes'.
Could you kindly take a quick look and let me know (I posted the link to the wayfair website). I very much appreciate your help with this.
Also please let me know what type of saw is best to cut this.
https://www.wayfair.com/home-improvement/pdp/ark-design-glass-sliding-closet-door-with-installation-hardware-kit-akde1107.html?piid=67685336

Comment: It would be helpful to [edit] your question to include a picture of the door itself and some/all of the text description. When (not if) that link goes down, the question becomes rather useless.

Answer (score 3):

The assembly instructions show that the door is held together with bolts including a pair of bolts that *appear* to be less than an inch from the bottom of the door.  Measurements are not provided but it appears that way in the diagrams.  So I would say no, you cannot trim an inch from the bottom of the door.  You would be reducing the strength and integrity of the door, which is a frame enclosing several glass panels ... not a good idea.

There are a lot of sliding doors that are *documented* to allow trimming of the bottom.  Maybe you should search for one of those, or one that just fits especially if you want one with glass panels.